# Mongoose Schema - How to create a schema where one of the fields is an array of key-value pairs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
 var db = require('../db');
 var post = db.Schema({
   msgtype: { type: Number },
   msgtext: { type: String },
   sender: { type: String },
   recipients: { xxxxxx },
   created_on: { type: Date }
 });
 module.exports = db.model('Post', post);
```

I want the field, recipients, is of the type - array of
    {
    email: {type: String},
    read: {type: Boolean }
    }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare `recipients` as an array:

```
...
recipients: [{
  email: String,
  read: Boolean
}]
...
```

To search for a `recipient` item, by the `email` field, do:

```
Post.findOne({'recipients.email': 'peter.w@gmail.com'}, function (err, doc) {
  if (!err) console.log(doc);
});
```

To update an item, just do:

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate(
  { 'recipients.email': 'peter.w@gmail.com' },
  {
    '$set': {
      'recipients.$.read': true
    }
  },
  function(err, doc) {
});
```

This way will set `true` to all `recipients` whose email is `peter.w@gmail.com` of the first document found.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo Medeiros - one follow-up question - in my case, how do I do find query to look for post documents where a recipient's email is, say, peter.w@gmail.com ?

Comment: Very helpful answer. Last question: how do I update the post document setting the read boolean to true for the recipient whose email is, say, peter.w@gmail.com?

Comment: Please update your original question, adding these two other questions. It'll be much better for others to read it, than having to read all these comments.